# Export All option in Wordpress.com exports only one page of content

Tags: wordpress, web, export

I have a site hosted on Wordpress.com. I want to export it to other wordpress site. When I go to Settings > Export > Export All, it exports only one page of site content in .xml file.
Is there any way to export all of the site's content in the .xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup of database and wp-content folder and upload it to other wordpress website. Make changes in wp-congig.php file accordingly.